# Mix multiple RTP streams into a single one

Tags: audio, udp, rtp

I am trying to build a basic conference call system based on plain RTP.

```
                         _____
RTP IN #1  ______       |     |      _______ MIX RTP receiver #1
                 |______| MIX |_____|
           ______|      | RTP |     |_______ MIX RTP receiver #2
RTP IN #2               |_____|
```

I am creating RTP streams on Android via the [AudioStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioStream.html) class and using a server written in Node.js to receive them.

The naive approach I've been using is that the server receives the UDP packets and forwards them to the participants of the conversation. This works perfectly as long as there are two participants, and it's basically the same as if the two were sending their RTP stream to each other.

I would like this to work with multiple participants, but forwarding the RDP packets as they arrive to the server doesn't seem to work, probably for obvious reasons. With more than two participants, the result of delivering the packets coming in from different sources to each of the participants (excluding the sender of such packet) results in a completely broken audio.

Without changing the topology of the network (star rather than mesh) I presume that the server will need to take care of carrying out some operations on the packets in order to extract a unique output RTP stream containing the mixed input RTP streams.

I'm just not sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I know two options:

- MCU or Multipoint Control Unit
- Or RTP simulcast

**MCU Control Unit**

This is middle box (network element) that gets several RTP streams and generate one or more RTP streams.

You can implement it by yourself but it is not trivial because you need to deal with:

- Stream decoding (and therefore you need jitter buffer and codecs implementation)
- Stream mixing - so you need some synchronisation between streams (collect some data from source 1 and source 2, mix them and send to destination 3)

Also there are several project that can do it for you (like Asterisk, FreeSWITCH etc), you can try to write some integration level with them. I haven't heard anything about something on Node.js

**Simulcast**

This is pretty new technology and their specifications available only in IETF drafts. Core idea here is to send several RTP streams inside one RTP stream simultaneously.

When destination receives several RTP streams it needs to do exactly the same as MCU does - decode all streams and mix them together but in this case destination may use hardware audio mixer to do that.

Main cons for this approach is bandwidth to the client device. If you have N participants you need:

- either send all N streams to all other
- or select streams based on some metadata like voice activity or audio level

First one is not efficient, second is very tricky.

Answer (score 0):

The options suggested by Dimtry's answer were not feasible in my case because:

- The middle box solution is difficult to implement, requires too many resources or requires to rely on an external piece of software, which I didn't want to have to rely on, especially because Android RTP stack should work out of the box with basic support from a server component, especially for hole punching
- The simulcast solution cannot be used because the [Android RTP package](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/package-summary.html) cannot handle that and ad far as my understanding goes it's only capable of handling simple RTP *streams*

Other options I've been evaluating:

#### SIP

Android [supports it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html) but it's more of a high level feature and I wanted to build the solution into my own custom application, without relying on additional abstractions introduced by a high level protocol such as SIP. Also, this felt just too complex to set up, and conferencing doesn't even seem to be a core feature but rather an extension

#### WebRTC

This is supposed to be the de-facto standard for peer 2 peer voice and video conferencing but looking through code examples it just looks too difficult to set up. Also requires support from servers for hole punching.

#### Our solution

Even though I had, and still have, little experience on this I thought there must be a way to make it work using plain RTP and some support from a simple server component.

The server component is necessary for hole punching, otherwise getting the clients to talk to each other is really tricky.

So what we ended up doing for conference calling is have the caller act as the mixer and the server component as the middle-man to deliver RTP packets to the participants.

In practice:

- whenever a `N`-user call is started, we instantiate `N-1` simple *UDP broadcast servers*, listening on `N-1` different ports
- We send those `N-1` ports to the initiator of the call via a signaling mechanism built on [socket.io](https://socket.io/) and 1 port to each of the remaining participants
- The server component listening on those ports will simply act as a relay: whenever it receives a UDP packet containing the RTP data it will forward it to all the *connected* clients (the sockets it has *seen* thus far) except the sender
- The initiator of the call will receive and send data to the other participants, mixing it via the Android `AudioGroup` class
- The participants will send data only to the initiator of the call, and they will receive the mixed audio (together with the caller's own voice and the other participants' voices) on the server port that has been assigned to them

This allows for a very simple implementation, both on the client and on the server side, with minimal signaling work required. It's certainly not a bullet proof conferencing solution, but given the simplicity and feature completeness (especially regarding common network issues like NAT traversal, which using a server aid is basically a non-issue) is in my opinion better than writing lots of code which requires many resources for mixing server-side, relying on external software like SIP servers, or using protocols like WebRTC which basically achieve the same with lots more effort implementation wise.